# The R-module $P$ is projective (the functor Hom$_R(P, −)$ : R-Mod $\to$ Ab is exact) iff the lifting property holds

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, functors

A module $P$ is projective **if and only** if for every diagram  [image]

there exists a homomorphism $\tilde h : P \to N$ that lifts $h$, i.e., such that $g \circ \tilde h = h$

I know many sources give this condition know as the  lifting property as the definition of projective functor but mine is

**Def:** $R$-module $P$ is defined to be projective if the functor Hom$_R(P, −)$ : R-Mod $\to$ Ab is exact.

**I have already one way.  Now I am stuck in the proving that if   Hom$_R(P, −)$ is exact, that is if I have a projective module according to my definition, the lifting property holds. Could you show me how to prove it  or point me to a proof?**

That Hom$_R(P,-)$ is exact means is that for every s.e.s $0\to N\to N' \to N''\to 0$, the exact sequence $0\to Hom_R(P,N)\to Hom_R(P,N') \to Hom_R(P,N'')\to 0$ is exact. How do I continue from here?

Comment: Exact functors preserve surjections of modules, so $g\colon N\twoheadrightarrow N'$ gets sent to a surjection $g\circ -\colon\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N)\twoheadrightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N')$. This is exactly what you are after.

Comment: @DaniëlApol So my definition of exactness of the functor Hom$_R(P,-)$ is that for every s.e.s $0\to N'\to N \to N''$, the exact sequence $0\to Hom(P,N')\to Hom(P,N) \to Hom(P,N'')$ is exact, from here I don't see how to use what you stated to get to the definition of the lifting property

Comment: This is only _left_ exactness of $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,-)$, which holds generally for any module $P$, not only the projective ones. Exactness would involve preservation of short exact sequences as well. If you want, therefore, you can extend the surjection $N\to N'$ to a short exact sequence and then apply the functor $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,-)$.

Comment: Yes, I was about to change that, so   my definition of exactness of the functor Hom$_R(P,-)$ is that for every s.e.s $0\to N'\to N \to N''\to 0$, the exact sequence $0\to Hom_R(P,N')\to Hom_R(P,N) \to Hom_R(P,N'')\to 0$

Comment: Good. Then turn the surjection $g\colon N\to N'$ into a short exact sequence $0\to \mathrm{ker}\,g\to N\to N'\to 0$. Applying $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,-)$, we see that the map $g\circ-\colon\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N)\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N')$ is still surjective.

Comment: @DaniëlApol Did you mean $g:N'\to N$ ? and every N' and N should be swapped I guess

Comment: Oh sorry, I was taking $N$ and $N'$ as in the diagram at the top of your question, not as in the short exact sequences you wrote afterwards. I will put all of this in an answer to aid readability.

Comment: @DaniëlApol Ok so for consistency I guess I should change N' and N in my definition of exactness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given a surjection $g\colon N\to N'$ and a map $h\colon P\to N'$, and need to produce a map $\widetilde{h}\colon P\to N$ such that $h=g\widetilde{h}$. We extend the surjection $g\colon N\to N'$ to a short exact sequence $0\to \mathrm{ker}(g)\to N\xrightarrow{g} N'\to 0$. Since $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,-)$ is assumed to be exact, we obtain another short exact sequence $0\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,\mathrm{ker}(g))\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N)\xrightarrow{g\circ-}\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N')\to 0$. In particular, the map $g\circ -\colon \mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N)\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N')$ is surjective, so we can find a preimage of the element $h\in\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N')$, which is an element $\widetilde{h}\in\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N)$ such that $g\widetilde{h}=h$.

Comment: Awesome, when you apply the functor to g, if I just plug in $g: Hom_R(P,g)$ it doesn't make any sense, because g is not a set, but it would if I'd write $F(g$), with $F$ the functor. So how do you manage this to get "Hom$_R(P,g)=g '\circ -$"?

Comment: The action of a functor on morphism is part of its definition, so you cannot really derive formally that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,g)=g\circ-$ (it is namely just the definition of the hom functor). See for instance here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom_functor .